# Некорректное положение выпадающего списка при использование компонента v-select из библиотеки vuetifyjs

Tags: javascript, html, вёрстка, vue.js

Доброго дня. Переписываю клиентскую часть приложения (sharepoint 2010) с jQuery на vue 2.5 + vuetifyjs (в текущий момент используется последняя beta). При использовании компонента v-select столкнулся с тем что список для выбора всплывает где угодно, а не там где нужно. Что я делаю не так и как это исправить? Ниже пример кода и скрин.
UPD: Кажется дело в определение местоположения элемента библиотекой. Если элемент отрисовывается выше границы root элемента (#app) то его можно опустить до верхней границы убрав css свойство топ.  На иные изменения элемент не реагирует.

```
    <v-flex>
    <v-select
    :items="[
      { text: 'М', value: 'М' },
      { text: 'Ж', value: 'Ж' }
    ]"
   v-model="indicators.IND_8_1"
   label="Пол"
   required 
   bottom>
  </v-select>
  </v-flex>
```

[image: скрин]

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос старый, но возможно кто-то на него наткнется как и я спустя года :)

Проблема в том что основной елемент `<v-app>` должен находиться в верхнем левом углу, так как от него идет позиционирование всех всплывающих элементов. Понятно, что если вы пишете приложение полностью на Vue то для вас не проблема обернуть все приложение в  `<v-app>` и он будет в левом углу и все будет ок.

Но если у вас, как и у меня, это только кусок, тогда временное решение - обернуть корневой элемент дивом и зафиксировать стилями `position: fixed;`.

У меня это главный блок но есть верхнее меню и боковое + снизу футер. Потому для таких страниц скролинг делаю в зафиксированном окне, а для окна отключаю. У меня скрипт сам прячет левое меню и добавляет в `body` соответствующий класс. Вам возможно стоит использовать `@media` для адаптивности

```
<div id="fixed-main-block">
    <div id="app"></div>
</div>

<style>
    html {
        overflow: auto;
    }

    #fixed-main-block {
        position: fixed;
        top: 170px;
        max-height: calc(100vh - 224px);
        overflow-x: hidden;
        overflow-y: auto;
    }
    #fixed-main-block::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: 8px;
        height: 8px;
    }

    /* левое меню показано */
    .menubar-show #fixed-main-block {
        left: 268px;
        width: calc(100vw - 280px);
    }

    /* левое меню скрыто */
    .menubar-hide  #fixed-main-block {
        left: 8px;
        width: calc(100vw - 16px);
    }

    /* Это чтоб высота вложенного vue не растягивалась по ширине видимого блока */
    #app > .v-application--wrap {
         min-height: auto;
    }
</style>
```

Конечно решение так себе, но оно глобально сработает для всех элементов.

Возможно ее решат в следующих редакциях, данная проблема описана в [ищью разработчиков](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/7703) но по состоянию на начало 2021 года и версии Vuetify 2.4.2 не была решена.

Comment: https://codepen.io/ymnik-13/pen/ZEpmYvB